# Parallax Scrolling working only with few sections

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax

I'm making a Pallarax Scrolling Effect on website. If i put 3 or more `section`, the effect is completely wrong... With 2 `section` this works perfect. Whats the problem?

Can see th effect here: http://www.alsite.com.br/parallax

And JSFIddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/JnncN/

I Put some color on background to see the error. The image need to get full, same like the first 2 sections.

My HTML:

```
<body>
    <section id="home" data-speed="10" data-type="background">
        <article>I am Absolute Positioned</article>
    </section>

    <section id="produtos" data-speed="4" data-type="background">
        <article>I am Absolute Positioned</article>
    </section>

    <section id="empresa" data-speed="3" data-type="background">
        <article>I am Absolute Positioned</article>
    </section>

    <section id="contato" data-speed="6" data-type="background">
        <article>I am Absolute Positioned</article>
    </section>

 </body>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $window = $(window);

    $('section[data-type="background"]').each(function(){
        var $bgobj = $(this); // assigning the object
        $(window).scroll(function() {

            // Scroll the background at var speed
            // the yPos is a negative value because we're scrolling it UP!                              
            var yPos = -($window.scrollTop() / $bgobj.data('speed')); 

            // Put together our final background position
            var coords = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';

            // Move the background
            $bgobj.css({ backgroundPosition: coords });

        }); // window scroll Ends

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the size of your background. Also I tidied up your width declarations. You should set a wid in `px` then a `max-width: 100%;` to ensure no overflow and scalability with window resize

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/JnncN/1/

Comment: not changed.. with colors is right, but when i put the background images, occurs the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

Having issue with section 3, path not defined. rest of section ids working fine. Please check your site's code

```
<ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#home" title="Home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#produtos" title="Produtos">Produtos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#empresa" title="Empresa">Empresa</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="Vendas On-line">Vendas On-line</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contato" title="Contato">Contato</a></li>
</ul>
```

In following section path to a href="" not defined

```
<li><a href="" title="Vendas On-line">Vendas On-line</a></li>
```